# ADB doesn't recognize my device in recovery mode

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, usb-drivers, side-loading, asus-zenfone-5

I have an ASUS ZenFone 2. I have tried using ASUS USB drivers and Google Android composite ADB drivers on my computer, but neither recognize the device while it is in recovery mode.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Reading between the lines, you're using Windows on your computer. Have you checked if the device is even found at all – i.e. does it show up in the device manager, and with what additional information?

Comment: yes it shows my device in device manager when my phone is on and plugged via usb (2.0/3.0 tried both) and also there in no exclamation mark which means my drivers are correctly installed. But when i boot into recovery mode the device manager don't show my device.

Comment: Which recovery are you using? The stock recovery probably doesn't support ADB.

Comment: I'm using stock recovery. Are you sure stock recovery does not support adb because as far as i know stock recovery does support adb. If google made adb for android then its suppose to work on stock recovery, why need custom recovery.

Comment: Maybe your stock recovery is too old. Try updating it if you can (although it's unlikely that it's possible) or install a custom recovery.

Comment: @ANURAGBHASKAR A Custom Recovery does many things including installing non-OEM signed `.zip` or taking real backups (Nandroid) to the least. Stock Recovery isn't tailored for such things. Besides, what Google creates as code isn't necessarily supposed to work on variety of devices in the wild. Anyhow, what are you trying to do with ADB in stock Recovery? Stock Recovery probably won't have any feature to allow `adb shell` and `adb devices` would be empty (at least in my Mediatek devices)...

Comment: ...It's the `adb sideload` which is mostly available but if you intend to flash any non-OEM signed `.zip` then do stop since it probably wouldn't work.

Comment: @Firelord I just want to know if commands like push, pull, install or wiping data through ADB works only with device on or they can be used in recovery mode also.

Comment: My Mediatek devices doesn't allow  in stock Recovery `adb shell` and `adb push/pull/install` since that might be considered detrimental to OEM's security model of device. I can see output in `adb devices` only when "Install from ADB sideload" options is enabled in stock Recovery, but it's limited to sideload only. If I try any `adb shell/pull/push` command I receive "Error:closed" output, possibly because pseudo-terminal from Recovery isn't available. Whatsoever the reason is you can try enabling ~"Install from ADB sideload" in Recovery and see if the `adb devices` command shows something.

Comment: @Firelord  Yes, I also get the same thing "error:closed"  in recovery mode but after enabling "apply update from ADB" it shows my device when i use `adb devices` command. I guess i have the same problem as yours. BTW if you get any solution for this other than installing custom recovery please do inform me. Thanks!!

Comment: A few questions. What Recovery do you use? Why do you need to be able to use ADB while in recovery, sideloading? Why not just copy-paste files while in recovery and flash from inside the phone?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, plus the device was shown with a yellow exclamation mark in the device manager but only when in recovery mode.

Solution was to install the Google USB drivers for this device again:

- Google and Download "Google USB Driver"
- Open device manager
- Right click device
- Update Driver Software
- Select "Browse my Computer ..."
- Select "Let me pick ..."
- Select "Android Device"
- Select "Android ADB interface" ...

Comment: Joined specifically to say thank you!  I'd been fighting with this problem for an hour.

Comment: With a Samsung Galaxy A6 in recovery mode connected to the PC, in Device Manager I found "Android Phone" (instead of Android Device) and instead of "Android ADB interface" I selected "Samsung Android ADB Interface". After that, the command `adb devices" worked!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it by updating Intel USB Driver for Android Devices. It is available here: [Official](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices)

Answer (score 1):

do you have android debug bridge enabled in developer options? i'm pretty sure that will enable it in recovery mode, too.

with your device booted, go into settings and choose "About phone (or tablet)." scroll down and tap on "Build number" 7 times.

now go back out to the main settings screen and you should see "Developer options." Select that and make sure the selection to "Enable USB debugging" is checked.

Comment: did you mean usb debugging mode? That's turned on, or something else should be checked too?

Comment: yea, i'll edit that.

Comment: `adb devices` actually works while my device is on, but in recovery mode it doesn't.

Comment: with the device booted and connected via USB to your PC, enter `adb shell getprop` into the command prompt. look for `ro.adb.secure` and `ro.debuggable`. `ro.adb.secure` will = 0 and `ro.debuggable` will = 1 if the device allows ADB access in recovery mode.

Comment: also, it looks like the device needs to be in active sideload for ADB to see the device in recovery mode. here's a [link](http://www.asuszenfoneblog.com/2015/04/how-to-flash-asus-zenfone-2-via-adb.html) that might help explain the process.

Comment: command prompt showing me `ro.adb.secure` =1 and `ro.debuggable` =0 ,  so that means **NO** ADB access in recovery mode. Is there any way to get ADB to access in recovery mode or I have to install a custom recovery?

Comment: unfortunately, no. the only thing you'll have access to with stock recovery and ADB is "apply update from ADB." what's your endgame? that'll help us figure out if a workaround is possible.